# Embedded Kafka Broker IP Not Resolving in Property File

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, apache-kafka, embedded-kafka

I'm facing an issue where my Kafka `ProducerConfig` is getting an invalid `bootstrap.servers` value because my unit test `@PropertySource` isn't resolving the `spring.embedded.kafka.brokers` property. When I dump my producer config to the logs, I get the following:

```
acks = 0
batch.size = 10000
bootstrap.servers = [${spring.embedded.kafka.brokers}]
...
```

Clearly, the property isn't getting resolved. Suppose I have the following embedded Kafka test.

```
@EmbeddedKafka
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class EmbeddedKafkaTest {

    @Value("${spring.embedded.kafka.brokers}")
    private String embeddedKafkaBrokers;

    @Test
    public void test(){}

    @SpringBootConfiguration
    @PropertySource("classpath:kafkaTestProps.properties")
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    class EmbeddedKafkaTestConfiguration {
    }

}
```

and my `kafkaTestProperties.properties` file is as follows:

```
embedded-kafka-brokers=${spring.embedded.kafka.brokers}
...
```

`embedded-kafka-brokers` will eventually be provided to Kafka's `ProducerConfig` through some underlying autoconfiguration.

Interestingly, the `embeddedKafkaBrokers` instance field in the test class does contain the broker IPs set by embedded kafka.

I've concluded there's an issue with the property source loading order, where `@EmbeddedKafka` isn't setting the broker IP system property in time for `kafkaTestProperties.properties` to resolve it. This problem arose after porting our code base to Spring Boot 2 and Spring Cloud Finchley SR2, where Spring Kafka APIs have upgraded.

I've tried removing `@SpringBootTest` and wrapping the `test()` code in a `SpringApplicationBuilder` to no avail.

Any advice as to how I can fix this? Perhaps I can leverage `@AutoConfigurationAfter` or `@Order`? Is there a way to order the loading of property sources?

Answer (score 0):

It looks that your placeholder is not valid.
Try to replace:

`embedded-kafka-brokers=${"spring.embedded.kafka.brokers"}`

with:

`embedded-kafka-brokers=${spring.embedded.kafka.brokers}`

and provide it to the producer using class with @ConfigurationProperties or using @Value("${embedded-kafka-brokers}").

[documentation link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-placeholders-in-properties)

Comment: I'm sorry, I actually have the unquoted version in my code. I've updated my post.